# Compare dates with Spring Data neo4j

Tags: date, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

When querying for relationships on a `java.util.Date` property, what syntax should I use? I tried just using a query like (this is just an example to show what I'm trying to do, so please don't pay attention to variable names there):

```
@Query("start n1=node({0}) match n1-[r:TYPE]->n2 where r.dateCreated>={1} return r")
Page<Relationship> findAll(Node node, long date, Pageable pager);
```

But it throws the following error:

```
Caused by: Don't know how to compare that. Left: 1339845862883; Right: 1339827156836
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.Comparer$class.compareValuesOfDifferentTypes(Comparer.scala:45)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.Comparer$class.compare(Comparer.scala:67)
at org.neo4j.cypher.commands.ComparablePredicate.compare(ComparablePredicate.scala:30)
at org.neo4j.cypher.commands.ComparablePredicate.isMatch(ComparablePredicate.scala:41)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.matching.PatternMatcher$$anonfun$isMatchSoFar$1.apply(PatternMatcher.scala:148)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.matching.PatternMatcher$$anonfun$isMatchSoFar$1.apply(PatternMatcher.scala:148)
```

I also tried by passing a Date but it just throws the same error but trying to compare a Long and a Date.

I am using spring-data-neo4j version 2.0.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the date property's long value is stored as a string in the graph (in newer versions of SDN you can define a @GraphProperty(targetType=long.class) on date fields.

So comparison will work if you pass in the parameter value as `String.valueOf(longValue)`

Comment: yeah I came to the same idea to change to a string instead of a long, why choosing to store it as a string instead of a long though?

Comment: and also, if it stores it as a String, passing a parameter as Date should automatically convert it to a String to avoid throwing the error, shouldn't it??

Comment: Right, that's true. But as we don't know (in SDN) what you write in your custom query it is hard to do any conversions. That is different in the derived finder methods though.